# SQL Server query getting duplicates value

Tags: sql-server

This is my query and I am getting duplicate entry here and I want to avoid that.

```
select TB100Desc, QNo,SerieShortName,LotID,LotName,
QuantityBalance as SendQty,WeightBalance as SendWt,InitialProportionalWeight as SendRWt,
0 as tnQty,0 as RtnWt, 0 as RtnRWt,
EstimateSizeID,NextProcessName,EstimateQualityID,previousprocessname,

case when NextProcessID IN (453,536) then 'Helium'
when NextProcessID IN (78) then 'Blocking'
when  NextProcessID IN (204) then 'Rejection'
when NextProcessID IN (366) then 'Indore'
when NextProcessID IN (240) then 'Orchid'
when NextProcessID IN (203) then 'RO Rej stock'
else 'Others'
end as mgroup,
YEAR(trsdate) as myear,
MONTH(trsdate) as mmonth,
DAY(trsdate) as mday

from V_LotTransactions (nolock)
inner join R_Serie (nolock) on R_Serie.SerieID=V_LotTransactions.SerieID
where status='a'
and trstypeid in(609)
and DepartmentAccountID in (30,31)

and (previousprocessid in ('3101'))
and NextProcessID=205
and trsdate between '2016-04-26 00:00:01' and '2016-04-26 23:59:59'

union

select TB100Desc, QNo,SerieShortName,LotID,LotName,
QuantityBalance as SendQty,WeightBalance as SendWt,InitialProportionalWeight as SendRWt,
0 as tnQty,0 as RtnWt, 0 as RtnRWt,
EstimateSizeID,NextProcessName,EstimateQualityID,previousprocessname,

case when NextProcessID IN (453,536) then 'Helium'
when NextProcessID IN (78) then 'Blocking'
when  NextProcessID IN (204) then 'Rejection'
when NextProcessID IN (366) then 'Indore'
when NextProcessID IN (240) then 'Orchid'
when NextProcessID IN (203) then 'RO Rej stock'
else 'Others'
end as mgroup,
YEAR(trsdate) as myear,
MONTH(trsdate) as mmonth,
DAY(trsdate) as mday

from V_LotTransactions (nolock)
inner join R_Serie (nolock) on R_Serie.SerieID=V_LotTransactions.SerieID
where status='a'
and trstypeid in(1002)
and DepartmentAccountID in (30,31)
and (previousprocessid in (3101,3105))
and NextProcessID=205
and trsdate between '2016-04-26 00:00:01' and '2016-04-26 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Did you check whether the View V_LotTransactions has already these duplicated rows or if the Table/View R_Serie? As you have pretty strict WHERE-clauses it looks to me that the UNION is not the cause.

Maybe you just simply use "SELECT DISTINCT" - but thats a little bit messy as it does not fixes the real cause.

Comment: @OlafWatteroth it is not having duplication in view/table

Comment: It would be worth showing us the data that you're querying and the expected output vs the actual output.

Comment: If you add the column "SerieID" to the output - is this also duplicated or do you have just similar data with different IDs?

Comment: TB100Desc QNo SerieShortName LotID EstimateSizeID NextProcessName EstimateQualityID previousprocessname
2.5-4CT Q161235 R16107242 72143125 R16107242-0106B AS Tops Stock C-Mk AS Manager Check
2CT Q161226 R16 72153615 R16 AS T C-Mk AS M
2CT Q161226 R16 72153615 R161 AS T  AS M

Comment: Please edit the question to include extra data such as this. Please also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help which will help you format your query correctly.

Comment: TB100Desc QNo SerieShortName LotID EstimateSizeID NextProcessName EstimateQualityID previousprocessname

2CT Q161226            R16        72153615     R16            AS T           C-Mk                      AS M
2CT Q161226            R16        72153615     R161    AS T    C-Mk                       AS M


I am getting the output like this with lotid getting duplicate, i don't want duplication

Comment: This looks *remarkably* similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882425/sql-query-for-union-all) (I.e. same `WHERE` clauses). If you're the same person, you ought to have *edited* the question rather than creating another account and creating a new question.

Comment: if you can help with the query than it would be appreciated,

Comment: you should yourself debug your query and find actually which join is causing duplicate value.then it will be easy to find a way to eliminate.Start with simple query then keep on increasing join one by one.Remove the table from join if your not using that table's column in resultset,use EXISTS clause instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a compare of your 2 unioned queries, the result shows only the following differences:

```
...
and trstypeid in(1002)
...
and (previousprocessid in (3101,3105))
...

UNION

...
and trstypeid in(609)
...
and (previousprocessid in ('3101'))
```

First of all, why is the datatype of `previousprocessid`  differing in the 2 queries? On first you search a **number**, on second you search for a **string**

Then, giving the facts that :

1. you only have slight differences in the WHERE clause
2. you have no specific column in the SELECT clause that would "qualify" the returned rows with a fixed value following the query from which they returned, for further treatment
3. you don't want duplicates

I don't see a reason for the UNION

Why simply not do this

```
select DISTINCT TB100Desc, QNo,SerieShortName,LotID,LotName,
QuantityBalance as SendQty,WeightBalance as SendWt,InitialProportionalWeight as SendRWt,
0 as tnQty,0 as RtnWt, 0 as RtnRWt,
EstimateSizeID,NextProcessName,EstimateQualityID,previousprocessname,

case when NextProcessID IN (453,536) then 'Helium'
when NextProcessID IN (78) then 'Blocking'
when  NextProcessID IN (204) then 'Rejection'
when NextProcessID IN (366) then 'Indore'
when NextProcessID IN (240) then 'Orchid'
when NextProcessID IN (203) then 'RO Rej stock'
else 'Others'
end as mgroup,
YEAR(trsdate) as myear,
MONTH(trsdate) as mmonth,
DAY(trsdate) as mday

from V_LotTransactions (nolock)
inner join R_Serie (nolock) on R_Serie.SerieID=V_LotTransactions.SerieID
where status='a'

-------------------------
-- THIS :
and (
     (trstypeid in(1002) and previousprocessid in (3101,3105))
     OR
         (trstypeid in(609) and previousprocessid in (3101))
  )
-------------------------

and DepartmentAccountID in (30,31)
and NextProcessID=205
and trsdate between '2016-04-26 00:00:01' and '2016-04-26 23:59:59'
```

If I am wrong, please explain the reason of the UNION

Comment: i ran the query you posted and i also get the point that without union also we can get the output. But with your query also i am getting the same number of rows in output and the duplicates vlue as well

Comment: @RedDevil so it means that you have duplicates rows in the same table and that your duplicates were not coming from the UNION. If you want to remove the duplicates, add a `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT`. I am adapting my answer accordingly

Comment: I used distinct as you mentioned but still the duplicate entry is coming

Comment: Can anyone have the suggestion.

Comment: @RedDevil If you want any further suggestions, edit your answer to add your resulting data (all of it). It is not possible that you still have duplicates after having applied the DISTINCT and there's nothing more we can do at this point